# Database on a separate server - backup .bak

Tags: c#, sql-server, backup

I have a database on the server shared on the local network. I would like to write an application that backs up the database from this server, but not on the server, but on the computer from which I started this application. That is, for a better understanding:

The database is on some Windows Server server. I have a laptop that is connected to the same network and has access to a database. On this laptop, I start the app, connect to the database and the .bak file is saved to the laptop, not the server.
At the moment I wrote only so much and unfortunately it doesn't work for me:

```cs
 private static void CreateDatabaseBackup(string connectionString, string databaseName, string backupFilePath)
        {
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            SqlCommand backupCommand = connection.CreateCommand();
            backupCommand.CommandText = $"BACKUP DATABASE {databaseName} TO DISK = '{backupFilePath}'";
            connection.Open();
            backupCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            connection.Close();
        }
```

This throws me an exception:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: „Cannot open backup device 'C:\Backup\backup.bak'. Operating system error 3(The system cannot find the path specified.).
BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally.”
```

Probably because of the fact that it is trying to save the file to the server's disk, and it does not have the path specified in the variable `backupFilePath`

I would like .bak to be saved to the disk of the device firing the application.
How to approach this problem?

Comment: Have you tried using a UNC path? Like `\\mymachinename\somepublicshare\backup.bak`. The SQL service would need access/permissions to the save location.

Comment: I logged in to the server on which the database is located, created a folder in the path C: \ Backup \ and started the program.
He made it without throwing an exception. I logged in to the server again, and a .bak file appeared in this folder.
There is a problem with the fact that this file is created on the server on which the base is standing, and I would like it to be available on another device (on which I launched the application).

Comment: You are using terms that are not familiar to the average person. The short answer is that the service account for the database engine must have permissions to that folder. Generally speaking, you can't and shouldn't try to backup directly to a machine on which your client program runs when your sql server instance runs on a different machine.